# Is it possible to have a function executed when a specific exception is raised anywhere in the program?

Tags: python

I want to add some custom retry logic to the AWS sdk (but this isn't specifically about that). So whenever it throws a specific network exception it waits and tries again and whenever it throws a specific auth related exception it calls a function that tries to update it's credentials and tries again.

I want to avoid adding/duplicating this logic everywhere I call the sdk

I could try to wrap the sdk in my own service- I guess it would be a function that just takes an AWS client object and method call?

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like register a callback globally so whenever a specific exception is raised a function is executed. Could I monkey patch the AWS client?

Is this possible? How does one normally do this sort of thing in a DRY light weight way?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Python isn't built that way. However, Python has a very flexible [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) with strong reflection capabilities. You can use those capabilities to wrap the original API. Something like this (untested, not production-grade):

```py
import original_api

class Wrapper:
  def __dir__(self):
    return dir(original_api)

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    original = getattr(original_api, name)

    if not callable(original):
      return original

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      try:
        original(*args, **kwargs)
      except SomeSpecialError:
        retry()

    return wrapper

wrapped_api = Wrapper()
```

The docs linked above have a special section on implementing a module-level `__getattr__` properly.

Comment: Is that a common pattern for handling something like this?

Comment: @user1028270 oh absolutely not, this kind of stuff is fairly insane. But this could be interpreted as an example of the Proxy Pattern. A more normal approach would be to wrap the relevant functions explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like register a
>   callback globally so whenever a specific exception is raised a
>   function is executed. Could I monkey patch the AWS client?
>
> Is this possible?

I don't think it is possible or desirable. When your program grows you might have other cases where that said exception is thrown, maybe even without you knowing.
You would end up with some very hard to debug side effects.

> How does one normally do this sort of thing in a DRY
>   light weight way?

[...]

> I could try to wrap the sdk in my own service- I guess it would be a function 
>    that just takes an AWS client object and method call?

You could do that, or even wrap the AWS client object in your own object and have function on it that calls it.

```
class ClientWrapper:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def do_something_until_it_work(self, parameter):
        sleep_time = 1
        while True:
            try:
                self.client.do_something(parameter)
                return
            except (MyException e):
                pass
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            sleep_time *= 2
```